# caption on hover does not work/show up

Tags: css

Whenever I hover the image, the caption won't show up..

please correct my CSS below.

what should I change?

thanks, cheer!

```css
   .gallery-item {
    float: left;
    width: 14.25%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.caption{
    display: none;
}

.gallery-item .caption:hover{
  display: block;
}
 
.gallery-item img {
    padding-left: 5px;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-item">
  <img src="images/event-1.jpg" alt="Sunday">
  <div class="caption">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the `:hover` in `.gallery-item` instead

```css
.gallery-item {
    float: left;
    width: 14.25%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.caption{
    display: none;
}

.gallery-item:hover .caption{
  display: block;
}
 
.gallery-item img {
    padding-left: 5px;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-item">
  <img src="images/event-1.jpg" alt="Sunday">
  <div class="caption">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

What happens in your code is that you putting the hover selector to an element that has `display:none`, which means you can't select it at all

Comment: just flip the class haha

Comment: No, not the class, but the selector

Comment: Yes the `:hover` selector